# what is the grammar of android java for function implemented in another function's parameter

Tags: java, android

It is very often in Android Studio with following codes for Function:

```
    private LiveData<String> mText = Transformations.map(mIndex, new Function<Integer, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(Integer input) {
            return "Hello world from section: " + input;
        }
    });
```

Another example OnClickListener:

```
    builder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.dlg_down_cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
```

May I know this is java grammar or Android Studio special format? What is the meaning and where can I learn more? Thank you!

Comment: You're looking for _anonymous class_.

Comment: Thank you chrylis! I searched this and got "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html", yes, it is. But a bit confuse may not relative: "interface HelloWorld", then "class EnglishGreeting implements HelloWorld", then "HelloWorld englishGreeting = new EnglishGreeting();"...I think the last one should be "EnglishGreeting englishGreeting = new EnglishGreeting();"

Comment: Either way will work.  Declaring the variable's type to be the interface (as the Tutorial does)  is generally better.  See https://medium.com/javarevisited/oop-good-practices-coding-to-the-interface-baea84fd60d3

Comment: In modern Java (8 or newer), you can also use lambdas for most of these (if only one method is required to be implemented).